# How can I get the node ID inside my implementation of hook_tokens()?

Tags: tokens

I am trying to implement a custom token using the following code.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_token_info().
 */
function hook_token_info() {
  $type = array(
    'name' => `enter code here`t('xyz'),
    'description' => t('module.'),
    'needs-data' => 'xyz',
  );
  $tokens['full_html_form'] =array(
    'name' => t('Full HTML Form'),
    'description' => t('Returns full HTML Form based on the node'),
  );
  return array(
    'types' => array('abc' => $type),
    'tokens' => array('mno' => $tokens),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_tokens().
 */
function hook_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data = array(), array $options = array()) {
  $replacements = array();

  if ($type == 'abc') {
    foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
      switch ($name) {
        case 'full_html_form':
        $output = core_module_get_node($node->nid); 
          $replacements[$original] = $output;
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  return $replacements;
}
```

I don't understand how to pass node ID to `core_module_get_node()`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are defining your own token type, you need to pass the node object to [`token_replace()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!token.inc/function/token_replace/7) in the `$data` array, for example as `$data['node']` or `$data['abc']->node`, as you are telling Drupal the token requires the 'abc' data.

Your `hook_token_info()` implementation is wrong, anyway. The correct one would be the following one.

```
function mymodule_token_info() {
  $type = array(
    'name' => t('xyz'),
    'description' => t('The tokens for the xyz data.'),
    'needs-data' => 'xyz',
  );
  $tokens['full_html_form'] =array(
    'name' => t('Full HTML Form'),
    'description' => t('Returns full HTML Form based on the node'),
  );

  return array(
    'types' => array('abc' => $type),
    'tokens' => array('abc' => $tokens),  /* << */
  );
}
```

From your code is not clear, but if the token is generated for a node, then you should implement code similar to the following one. (See [`token_token_info()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!token!token.tokens.inc/function/token_token_info/7) as guideline.)

```
function mymodule_token_info() {
  $info['tokens']['node']['full_html_form'] = array(
    'name' => t('Full HTML Form'),
    'description' => t('Returns full HTML Form based on the node'),
  );

  return $info;
}
```

Modules can define new tokens for token types defined from other modules. The Token module is an example of such a module.